# Regex to extract number between brackets that are after a hashtag in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, hashtag

I have strings in the format:

```
'I had a great time with @[2468] and @[1357]! #[1111] #[2321]#[1212]'
```

I want to be able to extract the numbers between the @ and # symbols, but I do not want the included square brackets. For example I would like to return:

```
user_ids = [2468, 1357]
hash_tag_ids = [1111, 2321, 1212]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to match all occurrences of the pattern, the `string.scan` method is what you want. Scan automatically returns everything that matches the pattern, so you don't need to use "capture groups" (the parentheses you see in most regular expressions), but you do need to use "lookahead" and "lookbehind" to match some stuff without including it in your result.

The two lines you need are:

```
string.scan(/(?<=@\[)\d+(?=\])/).map(&:to_i) # => [2468, 1357]
string.scan(/(?<=#\[)\d+(?=\])/).map(&:to_i) # => [1111, 2321, 1212]
```

- The `(?<=...)` creates a "positive lookbehind" which ensures that the preceding characters match `...`, but those characters aren't included in the matched text. In other words, `(?<=@\[)` will match "@[", but "@[" will not be included in the results returned by `string.scan`.
- Notice the opening square bracket, and the closing square bracket have a slash in front of them. This is because square brackets have special meaning in a regular expression (they create a "character class"), but since we want to match a literal square bracket, we must "escape" them with a slash.
- `\d+` means to match 1 or more digits.
- `(?=...)` creates a "positive lookahead" which ensures that the following characters match `...`, but those characters aren't included in the matched text. Same as the lookbehind above, but checks the following characters instead of the preceding characters. In this case, `(?=\])` matches "]" without including the "]" in the results returned by `string.scan`.
- `string.scan` will return an array of strings. The `.map(&:to_i)` part will run `string.to_i` on each string to return an actual integer value.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.scan(/(?<=@\[)[^\]]*(?=\])/) # => ["2468", "1357"]
string.scan(/(?<=#\[)[^\]]*(?=\])/) # => ["1111", "2321", "1212"]
```